# ¿Como puedo dejar "NO VISIBLES" los datos que guardo en localStorage o sessionStorage en el navegador mediante Angular?

Tags: angular, aplicación-web, local-storage, navegador-web

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, el cual trabaja por la parte Backend con Java - Spring y Frontend con Angular. Dentro de angular, se guardan varias variables en el localStorage, pero se visualizan por el navegador y están solicitando que estos no se vean. Quería consultar si existe un método para no visualizar los datos en el navegador de los localStorage, sessionStorage o alguna librería u funcionalidad que cumpla este requisito sin tener que persistir los datos en la BD?.

Comment: Si las variables son para usarlas en el front, poco podrás hacer, pero si son para ser enviadas al back, ya la cosa cambia. En todo caso, en ambos escenarios es posible que te encuentres ante un problema de diseño. Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia para poder darte una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Incluso los frameworks de autenticación muchas veces guardan los tokens en el session storage y el local storage. No hay nada de malo con almacenar la información ahí lo que si debes estar claro de la diferencia entre los diferentes métodos de almacenar la información. Incluso las cookies pueden ser visualizadas así que si los datos deben ser persistidos y ser accesibles no creo que tengas muchas opciones. Quizas puedas encriptar la información pero en materia de seguridad no es 100% seguro, solo un poco más dificil de leer.